# How to make sure border of slicers do not cover each other in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I like the current layout of my slicers, however if I try to select `Line`

[image]

The top border of slicer `Effective Date` covers `Line` slicer.

Any workaround in this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options.

You can select the `Effective Date` slicer and then go to `Format` -> `Arrange` -> `Send to back` so that it'll always be behind any other visuals.

[image: send to back]

If you don't want users to interact with the headers at all, there is just a new update in March, which allows turning it off in `Options` -> `Report Settings`:

[image: visual options]

More info [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-march-2018-feature-summary/#visualHeader).

Comment: Thank you Foxan Ng